# django-nose taking 15 seconds even when there are zero test

Tags: python, django, performance, django-nose

I'm using django-nose with `REUSE_DB=1` and have disabled all my tests just to see the setup time it takes.

```
localhost:MyProject rohitjangid$ python manage.py test  
nosetests --verbosity 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
localhost:MyProject rohitjangid$
```

Actual time taken for the overall process was on an average 15 seconds.

My obvious guess was mysql database and so I looked into logs and found that nose was running 
some `ALTER TABLE` queries. My logs:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJECP.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlsR0.png

Looking into logs, it seems like it is taking too much time even when it is not creating database everytime. Is this perfectly normal?

my setup: OSX lion with mysql 5.5, django 1.3.1.

Comment: more information :
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16961#no1